# Object as queryParams in Angular 7

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

I have an object:

```
let paramsObj = {
    mode: "resetPassword", 
    oobCode: "dsaSdsxSFXx", 
    apiKey: "OQPzWYkFNe", 
    lang: "en"
   }
```

I want to use this object as queryParams for router navigate:

```
this.router.navigate(['/action', { queryParams: paramsObj}]);
```

But this is doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I wrote `this.router.navigate(['/action', { queryParams: paramsObj}]);`, 
but this is should be `this.router.navigate(['/action'], { queryParams: paramsObj});`
, and then it work as expected.